# React: change state and range input value using a scrollable element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, range, state

Here I have a state containing the value of a range input:

```
const [currentRange, setCurrentRange = useState({currentValue: 0})
```

```
<input
 type="range"
 id="scroll-range"
 value={currentRange.currentValue}
 onChange={dragHandler}
 ></input>
```

and here I have a scrollable element that scrolls horizontally:

```
import ScrollContainer from "react-indiana-drag-scroll"; 
// I'm using this library to implement scroll on drag

const Slider = () => {
return(
<ScrollContainer
      id="scrolling-container"
      vertical={false}
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(100, 0.25em)",
        width: "4em",
        height: "50%",
        alignItems: "center",
        cursor: "grab",
        marginBottom: "1rem",
      }}
    >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
   
    </ScrollContainer>
  );
};
```

What I want is to change the range input value as I scroll through the ScrollContainer. How can I implement this?

Comment: did you try onChange in Scroll container??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ScrollContainer />` component has a onScroll prop to which you could add a handleScroll function which will calculate how much it has scrolled by using `scrollHeight` and `scrollTop` element properties.

1. Get a reference to the  component, using the `useRef` hook.
2. Add a onScroll prop to the ScrollContainer and attach a handler function where you will be doing the calculation.
3. The `handleScroll` function will do the main calculation. It will first have to determine how much the `ScrollContainer` has scrolled relative to its `scrollHeight`.
4. Make sure the `<input/>` has `min` and `max` value set to `0` and `100`.

```js
...
  const dragScrollElement = useRef(null); // 1.

  // 3. 
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollableHeight =
    dragScrollElement.current.container.current.scrollHeight -
    dragScrollElement.current.container.current.offsetHeight;
    const amountScrolled = dragScrollElement.current.scrollTop;
    const rangeValue = (amountScrolled / scrollableHeight) * 100; // To make the value between 0 and 100.
    setCurrentRange({ currentValue: rangeValue });
  };

  return(
    ...
    <ScrollContainer
      ref={dragScrollElement}
      onScroll={handleScroll} // 2.
      id="scrolling-container"
      vertical={false}
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(100, 0.25em)",
        width: "4em",
        height: "50%",
        alignItems: "center",
        cursor: "grab",
        marginBottom: "1rem",
      }}
    >
    ...
  );
...
```

```html
<!-- 5. -->
<input
 type="range"
 id="scroll-range"
 value={currentRange.currentValue}
 min={0}
 max={100}
 readOnly 
 ></input>
```

Actual working example is from the sandbox, so feel free to change as per your need.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-initial-scroll-getelement-forked-j8fke?file=/index.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)

Comment: Thanks, this was spot on. Although I would also like to add and ask how can I set a default scroll position for the `ScrollContainer`. I set the state's `currentValue` to 50 as default, and the range input does reposition to 50, but I also want the `ScrollContainer` to be scrolled at 50% as well.

Comment: That's basic algebra. From `const rangeValue = (amountScrolled / scrollableHeight) * 100; ` I can also find out the formula for `amountScrolled` i.e `const amountScrolled = (rangeValue / 100) * scrollableHeight`. Now we can set the `amountScrolled` value as the elements `scrollTop` on mount.